# Difference between sizeof(char) and sizeof(char *)

Tags: c, malloc, sizeof

I'm wondering if there is a difference between sizeof(char) and sizeof(char *) :

```
char *s;
s = malloc(sizeof(char*)*len + 1);

char *s;
s = malloc(sizeof(char)*len + 1);
```

Is this the same ?

Comment: `char` != `char *`; `char` is a character, `char *` a pointer to a `char`.

Comment: One is a single character, the other is a pointer to a character. Very big difference. You could also try printing out the values given by `sizeof`.

Comment: `sizeof (char)` = 1 byte, `sizeof (char *)` = 4 / 8 bytes. You have to ask what is common between the two, not the difference.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`char` is a character and `sizeof(char)` is defined to be 1. ([N1570](http://chimera.roma1.infn.it/SP/COMMON/iso-iec-9899-1990.pdf) 6.5.3.4 The sizeof and _Alignof operators, paragraph 4)

`char*` is a *pointer to* a character and `sizeof(char*)` depends on the environment. It is typically 4 in 32-bit environment and 8 in 64-bit environment.

In typical environment where `sizeof(char*) > sizeof(char)`, `malloc(sizeof(char*)*len + 1)` will (at least try to) allocate more memory than `malloc(sizeof(char)*len + 1)` if `len` is small enough not to cause integer overflow.

Comment: Ok thank you for your explanation, so in my case I should use sizeof(char) because I want to allocate a string of characters.

Comment: @Flaz Then, its enough to use `s = malloc(len + 1)`

Answer (score 0):

They are not the same. `char*` is a pointer to a `char`. You are misinterpreting `char*` as a "type" by itself.

`char` is size 1, and `char*` which is a pointer can be 4 on 32 bit systems and 8 on 64bit system (provided it is compiled as per the system).

Comment: Yes exactly, it makes sense now.

Answer (score -1):

First of all it is a good example that shows that `malloc` **should be casted** in C.

Let consider this code snippet

```
char *s;
s = malloc(sizeof(char*)*len + 1);
```

Reading it it is not clear what the author of the code was going to do. Did he want to allocate a character array of type `char[sizeof( char * ) *len + 1]` or he wanted to allocate an array of type `char *[len + 1]` or `char *[len]` but made a mistake?

It is evident that such an expressions in the malloc `malloc(sizeof(char*)*len + 1)` confuses readers and is error prone.

However if the author wrote for example

```
s = ( char ** )malloc(sizeof(char*)*len + 1);
```

then the compiler would report a diagnostic message. Or if he wrote

```
s = ( char * )malloc(sizeof(char*)*len + 1);
```

then it would be more clear aboiut the author intention.

Moreover between the pointer declaration and the statement where the memory is allocated there can be many screens of lines of the code and the worst the declaration can be in one file while the allocation statement in the other file.

```
char *s;
//....
//....
s = malloc(sizeof(char*)*len + 1);
```

Without casting the `malloc` it is very time consuming to read such a code.

As for the question. `sizeof( char )` is always equal to 1 and does not depend on used environment. While `sizeof( char * )` is implementation-defined and can be equal for example to 2, 4 or 8 bytes or even something else.

Thus this expression in the malloc  `malloc(sizeof(char)*len + 1)` is fully equivalent to the expression in this call `malloc( len + 1)` Again it is not clear seeing this statement

```
s = malloc(len + 1);
```

what type of objects is allocated dynamically. Whether there is allocated an array of characters or for example a two dimensional array of characters like `char ( * )[2]` and `len + 1` - is some even number and 1 is added to `len` because `len` is odd or even there is allocated an object of some other type.

So it is much better to write

```
s = ( char * )malloc(sizeof(char)*len + 1);
    ^^^^^^^^^
```

This code is self- documented and makes it easy to read.

Thus the difference between these two statements

```
s = malloc(sizeof(char)*len + 1);
s = malloc(sizeof(char*)*len + 1);
```

is that the first statement allocates a memory extent of `len + 1` bytes while the second statement allocates an extent of `sizeof( char * ) * len + 1` bytes  where `sizeof( char * )` is except very and very rare cases is greater than 1.