# reading string of unknown size

Tags: c, string

i wrote this function, which read strings char by char and increase the allocated size.
for some reason im getting randomly the error " _CrtIsValidHeapPointer" in VS2010, while reading strings with around 100+ chars.
i tried to debug it, but i really cant figure whats wrong

```
char *unknown_size_string(){
    int i=0, size=10;
    char *name=NULL, *alloc_check=NULL, letter;
    //allocates initial size of 10 bytes
    name=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*size);
    if(!name){return NULL;}
    //reads char by char until newline reached
    while((letter=getchar())!='\n'){
        *((name)+i++)=letter;
        //when the remaining buffer size is 1 byte, allocating another 10 bytes
        if((i+1)==size){
            alloc_check=name;
            realloc(alloc_check,(size+=10)*sizeof(char));
            if(!alloc_check){return name;}
            name=alloc_check;
        }
    }
    *((name)+i)='\0';
    return name;
}
```

any help would be appreciated.

thanks

Comment: The last `*((name)+i='\0';` could result in an error if string had exact length of 10 chars, you will not realloc it, then add '\0' at the eleventh position (i = 10)... Or maybe I'm wrong

Comment: I think i have it covered by allocation when 1 byte left, but ill try to see if it changes something

Comment: @MartinVerjans You're right. The check should be done accounting for the end null space.

Comment: There should be no byte left because addressing starts with 0th element (when you check for i+1, with i=9, you have just assigned the 10th element).

Comment: you might be interested in [`getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/getline), which does what you're trying to do, but probably more efficiently. Note that this function is not part of the base standard, but of an extension. Read the linked reference page for more details.

Comment: Ohh, you are right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from the comments about taking into account null-termination byte, the main problem here is:

`realloc` returns the new allocated area (which may be the same, may be not).

So you have to assign back `alloc_check` in `realloc(alloc_check,(size+=10)*sizeof(char));` or you just create a memory leak and keep writing in an old location.

```
alloc_check = realloc(alloc_check,(size+=10));
```

(well, when the size is greater, the location isn't guaranteed to change everytime, but it has to sometimes when there's not enough contiguous space)

Aside: `name=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*size);` => `name=malloc(size);` (size of `char` is always 1, and no need to cast `malloc` pointer)

Extract from [N5170](http://chimera.roma1.infn.it/SP/COMMON/iso-iec-9899-1990.pdf):

> When sizeof is applied to an operand that has type char,unsigned char,or signed char,  (or a qualified version thereof) the result is 1.

Comment: You're right +1. But not for `sizeof(char)`, it can be !=1 (i.e. on EBCD system) ;). C standards doesn't specify it.

Comment: @Frankie_C thanks for the UV. I've read `sizeof(char)==1` several times here, will check: found it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40679801/difference-between-sizeofchar-and-sizeofchar

Comment: @Frankie_C : `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be `1` by the C standard. It's just not guaranteed that that `1` corresponds to an 8-bit byte (refer to [`CHAR_BIT`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits)).

Comment: from my understanding in vs2010 even in *.c files the c++ compiler is used, and you must csst the malloc. I will do what you suggested when im near my code later.

Comment: @hellazari No, Visual Studio compiles files with a .c extension as C code, not C++.

Comment: @nos i agree, but vs2010 c compiler isn't C99 conformant, its not really c compiler its mostly c++.